# Eclipse Windows 10 Install Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install the NEON Eclipse IDE for JAVA Developers on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine and get a fatal error preventing me from installing. I have tried to install from a different mirror with no luck. Thank you all for any help.

Here is an image of the error:

[Neon Eclipse 64 Bit IDE Install Error Out Put Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN17c.png)

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check your installed ***JAVA Version***

I think, minimum java 1.8 should be installed in your machine.

If you have installed 32 bit java then eclipse should be of 32 bit.

If you have installed 64 bit java then eclipse should be of 64 bit.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I will add that I used a program called revo uninstaller to clean up previous versions of JAVA installs. Thank You/ Merci.